# Tax exclusive if coupon applied else tax inclusive in items

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have setup taxes inclusive for all my items and filled MRP in price. But now I want to apply tax inclusive if customer didn't applied coupon i.e. buying on MRP. But when customer applies coupon I need to apply taxes on after discount amount.

Is it possible with settings within Woocommerce or is there any plugin available?

```
For e.g.
**Case I**
Product MRP = 670
Shipping    =  50
Tax 18%     = 102
Final price = 670 (Including Taxes) 
It's Fine.


**Case II**
Product MRP = 670
Discount 40%= 268
Price       = 402
Shipping    =  50
Tax 18%     =  61
Final price = 452 (Including Taxes)
But I need tax to calculated exclusively on discounted price i.e. 402+18% = 474+50 (Ship) = 524
```

Comment: You're describing the default behaviour: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/coupon-management/#section-8 "Coupons are applied to the product price before tax is calculated."

Comment: Please see the updated question

Comment: @JacobPeattie please help